# Lua/WebDevelopment - How to get URL variables?

Tags: url, lua

I'm using **Lua** for web development.

How do I retrieve URL (get) variables?

---

For example http://example.com/?varA=999

*Psuedo Lua code:*

```
local varA = url.get(varA);  -- varA =
```

Comment: What lua framework / server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's standard library doesn't do networking. Check out LuaSocket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Lua code in Lua, you can use request_path() and request_uri() to read the URL, and global _GET for a parsed version that correspond to the URL get variables you mention.