# How to get current request URL in lua

Tags: http, lua, lighttpd

How do I get the URL of browsed page(GET request)?

On the loading page, I want to get the full, current URL of the current web page and store its value in a variable. For drawing the page I am using lp(lua) and HTML. I want to get the request URL in lua script in an lp file and store it in a variable. 
SO that depending upon the request URL I can draw different logic.
For server I am using lighttpd.

I know in javascript I have window.location but I want to do it with lua.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006467/lua-webdevelopment-how-to-get-url-variables?rq=1 From this looks like lua's standard library does not have such feature..

Answer (score 0):

You have lighty.env["uri.path-raw"] and lighty.request["Host"]
Look at lighttpd documentation for available variables using mod_magnet for LUA scripting